# What should be the messageType for a custom message?

Tags: rosbridge-suite, robotwebtools, roslib, rospy, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

I created a custom ROS message:

```
string message
int32 a
int32 b
```

I will need to publish the messages from the web browser (roslibjs) and show it on the terminal, using python. Roslibjs requires us to specify a messageType when we start a topic, for example:

```
var msgTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
ros: ros,
name: 'chatter',
messageType: <messageType??>
});
```

I don't know what would be the messageType here, for my custom message. I would appreciate any help  with this.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248977/what-should-be-the-messagetype-for-a-custom-message?/) by [nerdyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/28562/nerdyturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message type is the name of the package plus the name of the file. For example if your package name is `my_pkg_msgs` and the file where you defined the message is `MyMsg.msg`, then the message type is `my_pkg_msgs.MyMsg`.

You might want to check this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) (point 3.).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [jsanch2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/25919/jsanch2s/) with karma: 136 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nerdyTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/28562/nerdyturtle/) on 2016-11-29**:
Great! Thank you! :)